# Synchronize intersection points of two pairs of curves with fminsearch

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimize, fminsearch

I have two pairs of curves and every pair has an intersection point at a different time value (x-value). Now I need to **move** one curve of each pair **equally in x-direction** until both intersection points have the same time value/x-argument:

[image]

These are just examples, you can assume the **same monotonicity** (but maybe different shapes) for all my real cases like in my example. Also **curves of the same color have the same x-vector** (but **not necessarily equidistant**). Between two colors (1=red and 2=blue) **x-range and the number of elements can be completely different.**

input curves generated by:

```
t1 = linspace(0,3,30);
t2 = linspace(0,5,15);
x1 = t1.^2.*5;
x2 = -t2.^2.*3+50;
y1 = t1.*2;
y2 = t2;

ip_x = InterX([t1;x1],[t2;x2]);
ip_y = InterX([t1;y1],[t2;y2]);
```

The intersections I calculate by using the function `InterX` at **[File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22441-curve-intersections)** which returns the `x` and `y` value of the intersection point. The intended output for the example is just guessed to illustrate my problem.

## My question is, how can I determine the time delay between input and output?

```
[ t1,x1,y1,t2,x2,y2 ] = findIntersectPair(t1,x1,y1,t2,x2,y2);
```

My approach is using `fminsearch` but I run into problems, after some iterations.

```
function [ t1,x1,y1,t2,x2,y2 ] = findIntersectPair(t1,x1,y1,t2,x2,y2)

d0 = 0;

[d,dxy] = fminsearch(@findDelay,d0);

function dxy = findDelay( d )
    disp(['d = ' num2str(d)])
    t2 = t2 - d;
    ip1 = InterX([t1;x1],[t2;x2]);
    ip2 = InterX([t1;y1],[t2;y2]);
    dxy = ip1(1)-ip2(1);
    disp(['dxy = ' num2str(dxy)])
end


[t1,x1,y1,x2,y2] = deal(t1,x1,y1,x2,y2);
t2 = t2 - d;

end
```

**`d` starts with `0` and should be increased, until `dxy` (starting with `2.5` in this case) becomes `0`.**

This seems to work nicely for the first iterations, but at one point the change of `d` is to big, so that there is no intersection point anymore and the function crashes:

```
d = 0
dxy = 2.4998
d = 0.00025
dxy = 2.4995
...
d = 0.00175
dxy = 2.4936
d = 0.00275
dxy = 2.4898
...
d = 0.38375
dxy = 0.67101
d = 0.51175
dxy = -0.11166
d = 0.76775
```

**The logical conclusion would be to use `fmincon` instead.** But I'm lacking of the *Optimization Toolbox*. Is there any way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `fmincon` - the error finally was a quite simple one.

In this line: `t2 = t2 - d` I assummed `t2` would be the original one from the initial function call, but thats not right. It is overwritten with every iteration and therefore increasing gradually.

A temporary variable `tt` solved the problem.

Final result:

```
function [ t1,x1,y1,t2,x2,y2 ] = findIntersectPair(t1,x1,y1,t2,x2,y2)

[d,dxy] = fminsearch(@findDelay,0);

function dxy = findDelay( d )
    tt = t2 - d;
    ipx = InterX([t1;x1],[tt;x2]);
    ipy = InterX([t1;y1],[tt;y2]);
    dxy = abs(ipx(1)-ipy(1));
end

[t1,x1,y1,x2,y2] = deal(t1,x1,y1,x2,y2);
t2 = t2 - d;

end
```

gives the desired plot:

[image]