# matlab find intersection of two curves

Tags: matlab, math, matlab-figure

I need to find the current of a diode in Matlab there are 2 equations and I couldn't find an intersection point. There is no real intersection point in this functions but I need to find the closest possible current values possible (need 3 correct digits after point) current code is here;

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;
a=27;% tempature in celcius
b=2*(10.^(-14));%saturation current
q=1.6e-19;%electron charge
k=1.38e-23;%boltzman's constant
t=a+273;%temp in kelvin
v=-0.2:0.00001:0.715;%source voltage
i=b*(exp(q*v/(k*t))-1);%diode i-v characteristic formula
i2=(5-v)/1000;%kirchoff's voltage law formula
plot (v,i,v,i2)    
xlabel('Voltage -->')
ylabel('Current -->')
grid on;
axis([0.2 2 0 0.03])`
```

I need to find closest `i` and `i2` values. And because of I'm going to do it repeatedly I have to formulate it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you.

Comment: [This should help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331097/synchronize-intersection-points-of-two-pairs-of-curves-with-fminsearch)

Answer (score 1):

This solution makes us of the `min` function, which determines the minimum of a vector as well as the index where this minimum occurs:

```
[difference,index] = min(abs(i-i2));
disp(v(index));   % point where both curves are closest
disp(difference); % how close they are at that point
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of evaluating your `i` and `i2` curves numerically by directly applying the computations to the given range `v`, you could define two distinct function handles as follows:

```
i_fun = @(v) b .* (exp((q .* v) / (k * t)) - 1);
i2_fun = @(v) (5 - v) / 1000;
```

Once this is done, you can compute the curve values as follows:

```
v = -0.2:0.00001:0.715;
i = i_fun(v);
i2 = i2_fun(v);
```

This will allow you to use the [fsolve function](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) to detect the intersections much more easily:

```
diff_fun = @(v) i2_fun(v) - i_fun(v);
int_x = fzero(diff_fun,3);
int_y = feval(i_fun,int_x);
```

Full working example:

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

a = 27;
b = 2*(10.^(-14));
q = 1.6e-19;
k = 1.38e-23;
t = a + 273;

i_fun = @(v) b .* (exp((q .* v) / (k * t)) - 1);
i2_fun = @(v) (5 - v) / 1000;
diff_fun = @(v) i2_fun(v) - i_fun(v);

v = -0.2:0.00001:0.715;%source voltage
i = i_fun(v);
i2 = i2_fun(v);
int_x = fzero(diff_fun,3);
int_y = feval(i_fun,int_x);

plot(v,i,v,i2);
hold on;
plot(int_x,int_y,'ob');
hold off;
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: This is probably the best solution if the curves are indeed crossing, but there should be a final verification to find where their distance is minimal in case they don't.